# Cannot access MySQL Database - PID file could not be found

Tags: linux, process, mysql, socket

I am using a Linux Server from GoDaddy, and without any known reason, PID file could not be found! These are the errors I got:

```
 # mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

# service mysqld status
mysqld: unrecognized service

# service mysql stop
ERROR! MySQL manager or server PID file could not be found!

# service mysql start
ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.

# mysqladmin retart
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!
```

Comment: I run into this from time to time... Can you run `ps -ef | grep mysql` and post the output

Comment: @ryekayo -- I get this:
root     15953 20471  0 15:56 pts/0    00:00:00 grep mysql

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you can do. Since the process is not running and it is not finding a pid file, you can designate it in your my.cnf file:

1. Use a text editor like Vim or Nano to access /etc/my.cnf
2. Add the following: `pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`
3. Create the directory/file:

`mkdir /var/run/mysqld
 touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld`

4. Start up MySQL: `service mysql start`
5. Tail log files to make sure MySQL starts up correctly: `tail -f /path/to/mysql.log`

Comment: after stage 4, I get this:
Starting MySQL. ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.

Comment: Can you post the output and the contents of your log file in your question?

Comment: I am not sure which log to check. I think it can be something about InnoDB --- I tried to post the log, but it is too long